# How do I force content editors to upload images via ADAM in 2SXC?

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

In a content item, I have a "Link" field for "Speaker Photo" to let my content editors upload images. I only want my users to upload through ADAM (whether drag and drop or using the ADAM button). I want to prevent users from typing in (or copying and pasting) their own URLs. How can I force a link field to **only** accept ADAM?

Answer (score 1):

@Aaron - that's a great question. As of now, I believe there is no such feature.

If you think there is a wide use case for this, that others would really want this to, please open a wish-issue on 2sxc.

Answer (score 0):

I thought there was a way, but I couldn't make it happen. I hope there is an answer to this, if not, it is a great feature/wishlist request!

It is possible to do in code (in C# in the View), but that is clunky and not UI friendly since it would be after the fact. And its a bit detailed/complicated dealing with the Entity.Attribute[] stuff.

Hopefully Daniel or someone has some know-how or an idea or sees the need for the feature. I think it is very important just to stop hot-linking alone.